# PHP does not display error messages

Tags: php, error-handling

I installed XAMPP 1.7.4 (with PHP 5.3.5), the problem is PHP does not display any error messages. E.g. if I connect to MYSQL with `mysql_connect()` without parameters, PHP will not complain about the required fields.

Why is this?

How can I configure PHP to display errors?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To turn on errors at the script level, include at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
```

Alternatively, if it is *not* a production site and simply a development / testing site, you can turn on error reporting in php.ini.  Search it for these settings:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
;error_reporting  =  E_ERROR
display_errors = On
;display_errors = Off
```

Answer (score 11):

May be the display error is off

add in .htaccess file of your application.

```
php_value display_errors on
```

OR

use this at the top of your php script

```
ini_set('display_errors',"1");
```

Answer (score 1):

To show error message on page over browser for php script use following code in top of your php file.

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
?>
```

and there is another way to check php error code if you are linux ubuntu user execute following command on terminal.

NOTE : -10 is the number of message you want to show.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It possibly did override your settings in the php.ini. Check the php.ini for error handling parameters and make sure they're switched on.

Happened to me a few weeks ago, too

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in your program

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```