# How to get feedback on errors in PHP?

Tags: php

I just wonder how I can activate errormessages in .php. When I do php at home I always get messages like "No closing bracket on line 232" and stuff like that, but when I do .php at work there's no such feature. Guess it has something to do with the domain/server, so does anyone know how to activate this so I can easier find the errors?

Comment: Maybe this can help: [PHP 5.3 does not display error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680831/php-5-3-does-not-display-error-messages)

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: It's probably important to add, when to enable error reporting and when to turn it off. If you're developing in your **development-environment** then it's a good idea to set `error_reporting` in such a way that every error/warning/notice is shown. In the **production-environment** it's a bad idea to do that because the error-messages shown may expose sensitive information. Always keep those separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `display_errors` and or a bunch of the [other PHP error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) is turned off in the php.ini file you use at work.

Also, if you use something like [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt), it will give you a lovely working environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 settings you can manipulate on code level:

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

and

`ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

That should do the trick.