# header(); not working after log out ]session_destroy()]

Tags: php, redirect, header, logout

I have this code for my logout.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
);
}

session_destroy();
    header( "Location: index.php" ); //to redirect back after logging out
?>
```

Problem is that the header doesn't work. I don't know if it has anything to do with the code above.. but I don't think so, cause it works on localhost - wamp server. Is it then because of the server I'm using? Or is it something wrong in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an error message, please explain in what way it doesn't work, and ensure that you have `error_reporting` and `display_errors` enabled.

Comment: My guess is that it has got to do with the cookies.

Comment: Why are you resetting session on 3'rd line?

Comment: @DaveRandom it stays on on logout.php, instead of going to index.php

Comment: Try : Change `header( "Location: index.php" );` to `header( "location: index.php" );` 'location' NOT CAPITAL L

Comment: @MihaiIorga I'm unsetting all session variables

Comment: @PrasanthBendra where did you read that. The capital L is ok.

Comment: @MihaiIorga : that was just a guess, leave it if wrong :)

Comment: @AlinaGabrielaSingeorzan do what Dave said and post error.

Comment: @MihaiIorga there's no error. after I click log out I get stuck on the logout.php page, which is just a blank page, no error, nothing, instead of being redirected back to index.php as I expect by using header( "Location: index.php" )

Comment: Add exit(); after header line.

Comment: @AlinaGabrielaSingeorzan maybe you have some bytecode before `headers` please remake that file.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra Header names are case insensitive. There is a problem with that header, but that is not it - `Location` URIs should be absolute according to RFC2616. However afaik *all* web browsers will accept relative URIs.

Comment: A blank page often means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I added " ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0); " but it doesn't show any error still

Comment: @AlinaGabrielaSingeorzan - Second step is to fire Firebug (or your browser's debugging tool) and check whether the header is actually sent.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - I checked it with Firebug, no errors

Comment: @AlinaGabrielaSingeorzan - Fire Firebug and check whether the header is actually sent. You can see if in the "Net" panel.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the Header Redirect needs the data Buffering to be on, It's Probably disabled on the server, Try to add `ob_start();` After you `session_start();`

Comment: try this Instead:
 `echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=success.php">';    
    exit;  `

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Data buffering is just a hack to write spaghetti code where headers and mixed with regular output.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
header( "Location: http://hostname.com/full_path/index.php" );
```

Or if are getting the error in using the header then try this code:

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='http://hostname.com/full_path/index.php'</script>";
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the full path before - no result. Now I tried the second suggestion - works on my local host, but not on my domain.. so my guess is that is has something to do with the server

Answer (score 0):

Try this perhaps it works:

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=index.php">';    
exit;
```