# Not deleting the correct file in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, unlink

I am facing problem deleting the correct files. I am displaying the list of files uploaded by the user sorted by the time of upload (last upload first). If there's a list of 3-4 files, no matter which file I click to delete, the first file in the list gets deleted, the file last uploaded that is. Here is my page displaying the files a particular user has uploaded.

```
<?php
$uid=$faculty_data['faculty_id']; //Assigns logged in id to a variable
$query="SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY datetime DESC"; //Sorts by date time
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
if($uid==$row['faculty_id']) //Checks if the logged in id matches with id in DB
{
echo '<form action="delete.php" method="POST">';
echo "<strong>File: </strong>";
$url=$row['link'];  
$new="http://tofsis.com/fileshare/".$url; 
echo "<a href='$new'>$new</a><br/>";
echo "<strong>On: </strong>".$row['datetime'];
echo '<br><input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn" value="Delete File"/>';
echo '<hr>';
echo '</form>';
}
}
?>
```

And this is my delete page:

```
<?php
$uid=$faculty_data['faculty_id'];
$query="SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY datetime DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
if($uid==$row['faculty_id'])
{
 $url=$row['link'];
 $new="http://tofsis.com/fileshare/".$url; 
 $query="DELETE FROM uploads WHERE link = '$url'";
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 unlink($url);
}
}
 header('Location: my_uploads.php');
 exit();
 }
 else {
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Oops something went wrong!")</script>';
 header('Location: my_uploads.php');
 exit();
 }
?>
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong so that I can get my problem fixed?

[image: How my DB looks like]

[image: Screenshot of My Uploads page displaying files uploaded by the user]

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I guess you should change `$uid=$faculty_data['faculty_id'];` for `$uid=$_REQUEST['faculty_id'];`

Comment: @fedorqui: Tried that. Doesn't work. This is has something to do with the form or the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of changes should be make:

```
 <?php
        $uid=$faculty_data['faculty_id']; //Assigns logged in id to a variable
        $query="SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY datetime DESC"; //Sorts by date time
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        if($uid==$row['faculty_id']) //Checks if the logged in id matches with id in DB
        { 
        $file_id = $row['id'];
        echo '<form action="delete.php" method="POST">';
        echo "<strong>File: </strong>";
        $url=$row['link'];  
        $new="http://tofsis.com/fileshare/".$url; 
        echo "<a href='$new'>$new</a><br/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='$url' id='file_path' name='file_path' />";
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='$file_id' id='id_file' name='id_file' />"; // new line
        echo "<strong>On: </strong>".$row['datetime'];
        echo '<br><input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn" value="Delete File"/>';
        echo '<hr>';
        echo '</form>';
        }
        }
?>
```

On the delete page, this:

```
 <?php

         $file_id=$_POST['id_file'];
         $file_path = $_POST['file_path'];

         $query="DELETE FROM uploads WHERE id = $file_id";
         $result=mysql_query($query);
         unlink($file_path); //this should works on deleting the file

?>
```

That should do the trick ;)

Comment: Same problem exists. I tried deleting the second file, the first one got deleted.

Comment: I think your aproach is bad....making a select first and comparing....that comparing is fail

Comment: Could you please help the way you would do it then?

Comment: You want to delete ths last link according to a faculty_id....a faculty_id can have a lot of links???....is that your aproach??

Comment: I have a table that has list of files uploaded by different faculties. Say I am a faculty, when I loginto my account, I can see only the files I have uploaded. I added a delete button next to each file. (till here I got everything right). On clicking delete I want that file to be deleted from DB as well as directory. But no matter what I click, the last file uploaded gets deleted, that's the problem.

Comment: Just has i think....let me think a little and do an update on my answer...woa woa woa....can you show me your upload table schema???

Comment: I uploaded a sample picture. Check it out.

Comment: Worked like a beauty. But it didn't delete the file from the directory, deleted on from the database.

Comment: You want the file being deleted on the database and on the directory??.....i added the needed code ;)...you should check the $file_path var in order to be the same with your upload dir ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add another hidden input that stores the File ID and Get it in your delete script and use it

Answer (score 0):

You create a separate POST form for each available file but none of this forms contain any information about what file they refer to. I guess that `$_POST` contains nothing but a `delete` key with `Delete File` as value.

In your delete page, you read data from a variable that does not exist:

```
$uid=$faculty_data['faculty_id']
```

... and then you retrieve *all* files from the database to compare their ID against `$uid`. I guess you are removing all rows when the ID is zero.

To do:

1. Enable full error reporting. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).
2. Add a hidden field to the form with the corresponding ID.
3. Read form data from `$_POST`, not from an arbitrary variable.
4. Learn some basic SQL, such as the `WHERE` clause, so you can do something like:

   ```
   DELETE FROM uploads
   WHERE faculty_id=333
   ```
5. Learn about SQL injection. Use a library that provides prepared statements.