# Blank screen issue (Timeout)

Tags: cakephp, xml-parsing, timeout

I am getting an XML file through web service and converting it to array using the built in Cakephp function (_toArray). The xml file is fairly and big and when I assign the array to the template its showing a blank screen. It happens after the loading the page for 30 seconds.

When I print the array in the controller page, its printing the data correctly, but when passing the to template file its timing out (blank screen)

I would like to get suggestions to solve this issue

Comment: A blank page normally means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: Make sure you don't have any extra white spaces after the end ?> on any/all PHP files.  (and make a habit of not closing PHP tags on PHP-specific files).

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your script is timing out.  You can increase the time limit for this action by calling [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in your controller.

You will probably want to look into [Caching](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html) and the [CacheHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html) so subsequent views take much less time.

Comment: I did try the set_time_limit(0) and increased memory_limit in php.ini, but that didn't solve the issue

Its working well when the size of xml is small, so I need a solution to parse the xml and display it properly on the template without any errors