# Issue displaying UTF-8 characters submitted through a form back into the form

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I have a form where a user could enter a search term, basically it's a search bar at the top of the page. If the user has entered anything then the new page also contains what they entered, lest they forget, just as Google does.

First the page is set to use UTF-8 with (the page is properly UTF-8 encoded):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The input box is:

```
<input class="sb_input" name="q" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($displaysearch)) echo $displaysearch; ?>" />
```

Above this is some PHP code to clean up the search term just a little:

```
$search=$_GET['q'];
$displaysearch=preg_replace('@[^\p{L}| ]@','',trim($search));
```

The problem is that if I enter `Über`, the search box on the new page will display `�ber`, and I can't figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: You say the file is properly encoded as UTF-8? Then maybe your webserver sends back a HTTP header saying something different. Although this would be very odd. Ensure it returns the HTTP header `content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. You could achieve this by the line `header('content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` in your PHP code before any other output. [Manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: This seems like the form does not send UTF-8 but ISO.

Comment: @pvorb, I tried that but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @Alasdair Ok. So what happens, if you place an 'Über' directly into HTML (not going through a PHP variable)?

Comment: @pvorb, that displays correctly... but the manually entered text is still incorrect.

Comment: That implies that the form is somehow de-UTF8ing the input text. I tried accepted-encoding on the form, but it does not help either.

Comment: A potential workaround could be to use `utf8encode($displaysearch)`. But that's just a fix, not a solution to the real issue.

Comment: @pvorb, strangely enough that changes it to `Ãber`, so that doesn't work either.

Comment: @pvorb - [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/utf8_encode) is by no means a workaround given that we cannot assure that the input is `ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML `<meta>` tags are probably the most irrelevant bit. Make sure you've read and understood [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). Additionally:

- You are not testing whether `$_GET['q']` is defined. This suggests you've disabled full error reporting. If that's the case, it's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).
- You are injecting unescaped text into your HTML: you need to use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).
- You've omitted the [`u` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in your regular expression, thus your text is being handled as single-byte.

Comment: `$_GET['q']` is always defined, that's the only way this page can be reached. I will try your suggestions, thanks.