# select matching data in mysql table by setting mysql session variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display a list of users who live locally to the user who is logged in. so if the logged in session user has a postcode of 'm3 4' and 5 other users have a postcode beginning with 'm3 4' then these users will be shown to the user.

My table is laid out like this:

```
id  |   user_id  | user_postcode
1          2          M3 4
2          3          SM2 7
3          4          M3 4
```

so in this scenario user 2 will be shown to user 4 who is logged in because their post codes match.

I'm trying to do this in mysql and it works when i put the postcode in manually like so:

```
AND ptb_stats.user_postcode='M3 4'
```

but I'm trying to make it user session specific, so if the logged in user / $_SESSION[user_id'] has the same post code as other users.

i'm trying to do it this way, but it's showing all the users without postcodes.

```
function get_local_users() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "
            SELECT *
            From ptb_stats, ptb_users
            WHERE ptb_stats.user_id=ptb_users.id
            AND ptb_stats.user_postcode='".$_SESSION['user_postcode']."'";
            $local_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($local_set);
            return $local_set;
        }
```

i think its doing this because ".$_SESSION['user_postcode'] isn't set and i havn't set ".$_SESSION['user_postcode'] as a variable or anything because i don't know how to do that, but ".$_SESSION['user_id'] is set up as a variable as this was done by a friend of mine who never showed me how to do it. so i don't know how i can solve this one and wether i can somehow user ".$_SESSION['user_id'].

Can i not simply add any column name to the $_SESSION['columnHere'] ?

i have been working on this for over a day now and i can't figure it out, I'm really new to php and mysql and i know this may seem a silly question but please can someone show me because I'm trying all sorts and getting no where.

Comment: What are you declaring a `global $_SESSION` for? Are you trying to get the session variable `$_SESSION['user_postcode']`? Is it set somewhere else?... sidenote: `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated. Please see [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for more details.

Comment: i don't actually need the global $session i just put it int there to double check something. i am just trying to basically tell the query that if the user who is logged in / $_SESSION['user_id'] - which is set as a variable, has their 'user_postcode' - which is a column in my table that it should bring up all matching users with the same postcode

Answer (score 0):

PHP and SQL are different languages. You are using PHP to generate SQL code but that's all. So, in the end, all that matters is what `$query` contains. Just inspect its value...

```
var_dump($query);
```

... and use your favourite MySQL client to run the generated SQL code. That will tell you where the error is.

The fact that we can see `global $_SESSION;` in your code suggests that it's your first attempt with sessions. Most likely, sessions are not even working —perhaps you forgot `session_start()`— and `$_SESSION['user_postcode']` is triggering this notice:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

To see such notices you need to configure full error reporting in PHP. Here's a [brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Additionally, I recommend [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).