# Is the exec run sequentially causing the 500 internal server error?

Tags: php, system, exec

```
exec("convert -density 40 -colorspace srgb ".$incoming_path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$incomingPdf." -quality 80 ".$gen_folder_path.'med'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$incomingBaseName.".jpg");

        checkSuccess($incomingBaseName.'.jpg',$gen_folder_path.'med'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,'med');

exec("convert -density 15 -colorspace srgb ".$incoming_path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$incomingPdf." -quality 80 ".$gen_folder_path.'thumb'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$incomingBaseName.".jpg");

        checkSuccess($incomingBaseName.'.jpg',$gen_folder_path.'thumb'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,'thumb');
```

The above code is running the two command by using PHP, the problem is , when the first exec is running , will it go directly to checkSuccess() and go to the next exec()? Will the two exec collision ? Since the program sometimes encounter the 500 internal server error. I am wondering is this the cause?

Also, if I add a sleep() eg. 30 second,  is it a good solution ? thanks.

Comment: Also, I can not simply using error_reporting (E_ALL) to check the error cause, it will redirect to the error page.

Comment: A 500 status code means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: Thanks, it will redirect to the Server Error page?

Comment: Have you checked the web server's error log?

Comment: I am afraid i can not access it , is it the only way to do checking ?

Comment: I'd say you're developing directly on the live site and such site is configured to hide error messages at all cost, which is OK in a live site. As I said, it's impossible to do serious coding if you can't even see error messages. You should configure a local stack and develop in a computer you have full control on. Meanwhile, you should at least try to enable "log_errors" and "error_log" so you can send logs to a file you can actually read.

Comment: Thanks, I look at the log first then