# Why can I connect to a MySQL server with PHP in XAMPP but not Uniform Server?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a complete newbie to PHP, MySQL, and server-based languages. I am learning via a simple localhost (127.0.0.1) server. This code:

```
$dbc=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','aPassword','aDatabase') or die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error());
```

connects fine with XAMPP's base configuration, but not Uniform Server's. No error messages. Any idea why--or where I would look to figure it out? ... I am too new to all this to even know where to start looking!

Thanks, as always.

Comment: Please note you are using mysqli and then mysql_error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blank page means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

My educated guess is that you haven't enabled the `mysqli` extension. If that's the case, as soon as you get error reporting working you'll be warned about it.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful info! ... I configured PHP to display error messages. My error is "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." MySQL and Apache *are* running, though.