# Internal Server Error after long time running of php script

Tags: php

I have some db query in my php file, approximately after 40 second, happened `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`, though in `php.ini` file this settings are set:

```
memory_limit         8192M
max_execution_time   120
```

I think this settingst is enough, other what reason may causes `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` after long time running of php script?

Comment: That's a generic HTTP status code that means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: I set `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(~0);` but php not returns any error, after several second, just commonly `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` message returned.

Comment: Then you need to find the web server logs. Guessing is the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

set

```
ini_set('max_execution_time' ,0);       
ini_set('set_memory_limit', -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but this might work for someone.

Use this for every iteration of your loop `sleep(0.5);` 
0.5 is user defined you can change it.