# Vtiger uprage 5.4 new account creating page goes blank

Tags: crm

Viger CRM 5.4 after upgrading from 5.2 to 5.3 and then 5.3 to 5.4, when I save new user info and save, page goes blank.

Comment: A blank page means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: I have enabled logs in php.ini but no error is being displaed in apache error logs.

Comment: Have you configured PHP to write in Apache logs? I'm not sure it's a good idea. Whatever, in your development box you should configure PHP to display error messages on screen—otherwise, they'll possibly go unnoticed.

Comment: I have configured error_logs = "error_log = "C:\Program Files\vtigercrm-5.1.0\apache\logs\nehru_php_error.logs"

Comment: But log file is not being created

Comment: Please let me know if you need my php.ini file to check

Comment: I checked one thing more that is in error one dll file is missing: secars.dll   can it be cause of it