# PHP doesn't insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'am trying to do very simple php page and have some kind of problem here. the page works and everything but there is nothing coming to mysql. When I press submit it prints insert into DrinkHistory(CustomerId,DrinkId,SellerId) values('1','3','2')Your Data Inserted. But when I login to phpmyadmin there is nothing in DrinkHistory table.

the code is below

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","******","*******","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Mene kotii ku et mitää osaa: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Insert Data

@$a=$_POST['CustomerId'];
@$b=$_POST['DrinkId'];
@$c=$_POST['SellerId'];
if(@$_POST['submit'])
{
echo $s="insert into DrinkHistory(CustomerId,DrinkId,SellerId) values('$a','$b','$c')";
echo "Your Data Inserted";
mysql_query($s);
}

?>


<center>
<form method="post">
<table width="100%" height="245" border="1" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
<tr><td width="112" height="26">Asiakas</td>
<td width="100"><input type="radio" name="CustomerId" value="1"/>Jokirinne Niko</td>
</tr>

<tr><td rowspan="2">Juoma</td>
<form method)="post">
<td height="28"><input type="radio" name="DrinkId" value="2"/>Kalja</td>
<td height="28"><input type="radio" name="DrinkId" value="3"/>Lonkero</td>
<td height="28"><input type="radio" name="DrinkId" value="4"/>Siideri</td>
<td height="28"><input type="radio" name="DrinkId" value="5"/>Fisu</td>
<td height="28"><input type="radio" name="DrinkId" value="6"/>Tequila</td>
<td height="26"><input type="radio" name="DrinkId" value="7"/>MustikkaShotti</td>
</tr>
<td height="33"></tr>


<tr><td rowspan="3">Myyjä</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="SellerId" value="1"/>Niko Jokirinne</td>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="SellerId" value="2"/>Tanya Lickorish</td>
<tr>

<tr><td height="62"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Juo"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysqli_connect() + mysql_query() - error handling = problems ;-)

Comment: add mysql_query($s) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Can't see anything obvious wrong, can you have your table structure and the result of the $s echo?

Comment: nice equation alvaro :)

Comment: Also, be careful because you have to <form> tags in your HTML, and the second one is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be omitting the connection string (using mysql_query instead of mysqli_query) and error verification. Try this:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","******","*******","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Mene kotii ku et mitää osaa: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Insert Data

@$a=$_POST['CustomerId'];
@$b=$_POST['DrinkId'];
@$c=$_POST['SellerId'];
if(@$_POST['submit']) {
    echo $s = "insert into DrinkHistory(CustomerId,DrinkId,SellerId) values('$a','$b','$c')";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $s)) {
        echo "Your Data Inserted";
    } else {
        echo "Error inserting data: ".mysqli_error();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: now it says: "insert into DrinkHistory(CustomerId,DrinkId,SellerId) values('1','3','2')Error inserting data:"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the function name. I just edited it to correct it. By the way: that code is 100% vulnerable to sql injection. You should always test the data you receive before trying to execute a query with interpolated variables received from a POST.

Answer (score 0):

You have several database libraries to choose from but, once you decide, you need to stick to one. You cannot start a connection with the new mysqli extension:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","******","*******","test");
```

... and then try to query the database with the legacy deprecated functions:

```
mysql_query($s);
```

If you are not getting a blattant error message on screen you've probably failed to configure PHP to display error messages in your development box.That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Finally, you verify if your connection fails:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
```

... but you don't test if your query fails.

Comment: After i wrote ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);   into code it says Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/database.php on line 29 Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/database.php on line 32 Error inserting data:

Comment: I'm glad my second and third tips helped you. Now head to the first one ;-)