# how do you connect to oracle db from php

Tags: php

I am trying to connec to oracle table from php. I have odbc configured and tested that it works. I have the following php file that I created to test the connection but I get

This is the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('<dsn name>','<username>','<password>');
if (!$conn) {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
$sql="SELECT T."Node" from <table name> T";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs) {exit("Error in SQL");}
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<th>Companyname</th>";
echo "<th>Contactname</th></tr>";
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
    $compname=odbc_result($rs,"CompanyName");
    $conname=odbc_result($rs,"ContactName");
    echo "<tr><td>$compname</td>";
    echo "<td>$conname</td></tr>";
}
odbc_close($conn);
echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

My version :

```
C:\PHP>php --version
PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2013 19:16:29)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I configured error on on the php.ini file and I am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 8
```

it is complaining about the sql line. it does not like this T."Node" ( the double quotes). Is it possible to escape the double quotes within the sql line in php. How would I address this?

Comment: A 500 status code (or a blank page) normally means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: You might well find the error message in the error logs for your server however.

Comment: Check the server error log. it'll have more details about the 500 error. Plus, command-line php information is rarely useful for diagnosing web-based problems. It's entirely possible to have multiple versions of PHP installed, and web v.s. cli can have different configurations on top of that.

Comment: @Alvar G.Vicorio, I have updated the orinal post.

Comment: Right, you have a syntax error, nothing related to ODBC or Oracle. Have a look at the [strings](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) section in the PHP manual. There're also IDEs with PHP syntax checking.

Comment: And, before you ask, `<table name>` is not a valid identifier in Oracle. Why the `<>`?

Comment: Álvaro, it's common to anonymize code before posting on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sql="SELECT T."Node" from <table name> T";
```

must be

```
sql="SELECT T" . $node. " from <table name> T";
```

if $node is a var,

```
sql="SELECT T.\"Node\" from <table name> T";
```

otherwise to escape the quotes.

You might want to use some editor with syntax and error highlighting, e.g. netbeans, eclipse, notepad++...

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the quotes around the table. Those are not needed.

```
$sql="SELECT T.Node from <table name> T";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error here:

$sql="SELECT T."Node" from  T";

use literal string (single quotes) if you want to use quotes inside the string:

$sql='SELECT T."Node" from  T';