# move_uploaded_file & symbolic-linked directory

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I'm a beginner in PHP.

I have an application that allows donwloading files. Some of them are quite big.

On my server, there were two partitions.

The first one was getting tiny, as files were uploaded.

So I decided to move my "uploads" directory to the other partition and to make a symbolic link of it so that paths remain the same.

The problem is that the uploading fails with symbolic folder but doesn't fail when the upload folder is physic

Also, the mkdir command line doesn't work when applied to a symbolic linked folder.

Thanks in advance for the answer or any help!

Mat'

Comment: How does the command fail, what error are you getting?

Comment: Just a thought, but you might want to try adding "Options +FollowSymLinks" to your .htaccess file.

Comment: "Does not work" as only description suggests that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answers. Finally, I contacted my server administrator who changed the access rights on the symb linked folder. The problem is that people couldn't access (with reading mode) to the 2 preceding top level folders. With the new rights, it was ok..