# PHP- sendgrid add multiple emails to a recipient list returns error 500

Tags: php, sendgrid

I have the following code:

```
static function getContext($data) {
    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query ( $data ) 
        ) 
    );

    return stream_context_create ( $options );
}

static function addEmailsToRecipientList($name, $emails) {

    $url = 'https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json';

    $temp = array();
    foreach($emails as $email){
        $temp[] = array('email' => $email, 'name' => 'unknown');
    }

    $data = array (
            'list' => $name,
            'data' => json_encode($temp),
            'api_user' => $api_user_name,
            'api_key' => $api_password
    );

    $context = SendGridAPI::getContext ( $data );
    return file_get_contents ( $url, false, $context );
}
```

When I pass to addEmailsToRecipientList a name of an existing list and an array of email addresses that I want to add to it, I get an error 500 (internal server error).

Adding a single email ($temp = array('email' => $email, 'name' => 'unknown')) works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A 500 Internal Server Error (or a blank page) means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: They write in the API documentation "Add one or more emails to a Recipient List" Could it be that adding multiple emails is not supported?!

http://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/when_adding_recipients_i_get_a_database_error_has_occurred

Comment: Since you cannot see the error message with the exact details, it could be anything.

Comment: The server error is not from my server but from sendgrid.
I get:
file_get_contents(https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. And a stack trace. Should there be more info?

Answer (score 3):

Solved it! :)

```
//listname: the name of an existing recipients list
//$emails: an array of emails
static function addEmailsToRecipientList($listname, $emails){
    $username= 'sendgrid_username';
    $password= 'sendgrid_password';

    $url = 'https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?api_user='.$username.'&api_key='.$password; 

    $str= '&list=' . $listname;  
    for ($i=0;$i<count($emails);$i++) {
        $str.= '&data[]={"email":"'.$emails[$i] . '","name":"unknown'. $i .'"}';
    }

    return file_get_contents($url . $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scripts with a some touchs works very fine, i add the urlencode, the json_decode and simulated name for the email.

```
    $url = 'https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?api_user='.$username.'&api_key='.$password; 

    $str= '&list=' . $listname;  
    foreach ($data as $email) {
        $attributes = explode("@", $email);
        $str.= '&data[]=';
        $str.= urlencode('{"email":"'. $email . '","name":"'. ucfirst($attributes[0]) .'"}');
    }

    $results = file_get_contents($url . $str);
    $results = json_decode($results, TRUE);
    return (isset($results['inserted'])) ? $results['inserted'] : 0;
```