# PHP evades mysql functions and cant connect mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So i installed LAMP, in ubuntu 12.04 LT, and apache, php, phpmyadmin and mysql works fine independently, but for example i have a php file:

```
$conexion = mysql_connect("127.0.1.1", "root", "password") or die("<p class='error'>Lo             sentimos no se puede conectar a la base de datos.</p>");

$database = 'elBlog';
mysql_select_db($database, $conexion) or die("<p class='error>Lo sentimos, no se puede conectar...</p>");
```

Also i tried PDO:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=elBlog', "root", "password");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Php just evades this code, i mean is not even display an error message not for php not for mysql.
Looking around in the web i installed all the libraries that php and mysql needs.
what is wrong with this??

apache works fine, e.g. the phpinfo file for test is working.
phpmyadmin also works fine i already create a DB.
what else im missing??
Thanx for your help...

Comment: If there's no error message, than what is the problem?

Comment: See [PHP Does Not Display Error Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5680831)

Comment: Also, Don't use `mysql` extension, use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: 127.0.1.1 -> 127.0.0.1 ???

Comment: @robbmj [According to this RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3330) all of 12.0.0.0/8 is reserved for loopback on linux systems, so you could basically ping everything from 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254 and it would behave the same, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Indeed, I looked this up after I made my comment and learned a few new things. http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2013/07/msg00809.html

Comment: The PDO MySQL DSN does not have spaces. Change it to `host=localhost;dbname=elBlog`. That being said, you should have seen the error in your `catch` block.

Comment: @Phil  PDO needs explicit encouragement before making errors public: [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Really? The PDO constructor should throw an exception on failure. That's been my experience and it's also what the manual says.

Comment: thnx for the replies... the thing is that... is like php and mysql don't know each other... i changed the 127.0.0.1 and still not working, i already use PDO like i said in the post an also mysqli and still not working... maybe is a config of php.ini or my.conf i dont know...