# PDO - Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO so please bear with me. I'm trying to convert my old mysql to PDO but I am getting a "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in functions.php on line 5".

So this is functions.php:

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
function getSlug($param){
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE slug = ?");
    $sth->execute(array($param));
    $slug = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $slug;
}
?>
```

And this is page that generates the error:

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
$param = $_GET['param'];
$slug = getSlug($_GET['param']);    
?>
```

It seems like it's the last line `$slug = getSlug($_GET['param']);` that's causing the issue but I can't work it out, or it might be something elsewhere.
Thanks

Comment: PDO apart, you're trying to use a global variable from a function. If you don't get a notice, you haven't configured PHP to display errors. You need to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `$conn` into the `getSlug` function, otherwise it doesn't know what that variable is (and you get your error message):

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

function getSlug($conn, $param) {
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE slug = ?");
    $sth->execute(array($param));
    $slug = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $slug;
}
?>
```

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
$param = $_GET['param'];
$slug = getSlug($conn, $param);
?>
```

Comment: Updated to reflect that fact.

Comment: This is great. Now when I do `<?php echo print_r($slug); ?>` I get everything returned (including 'accept') but when I do `<?php echo $slug['accept'] ; ?>` nothing is returned. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to do: `echo $slug[0]['accept'];` to print out the value of the `accept` column from the first row returned...

Comment: @aphextwig - That shows that you still haven't enabled error reporting.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario how do I do that?

Comment: Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).