# TCPDF still not working for me

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am unsure at what I am doing wrong. I am trying to use tcpdf to generate a pdf from my form. When I click submit It just brings up a blank webpage and I do not receive any pdf at all. When I link the examples to see if it is an install problem they work flawlessly. is there anything I can do to fix this?

My html

```
<h2>Proto/Addendum Form</h2>
<p>
<form method="post" action="pdfcreate.php">
Job #: <input type="text" name="jobnum">
<br>
Program: <input type="text" name="program"><br />
Ship Date: <input type="text" name="shipdate"><br />
Description: <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:85%" name="description"><br /><br />
Proto Verified By: <input type="text" name="name"><br /><br />
Additional Notes: <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:85%" name="notes"><br />
<br /><br />
<h2>White Stock</h2>
Filename<input type="text" name="filename1" style="width:85%"><br />
Doc size<input type="text" name="Docsize1" size="6">
FC<input type="checkbox" name="fc1" value="fc">
DC<input type="checkbox" name="dc1" value="dc">
Flip<input type="checkbox" name="flip1" value="flip">
Quantity<input type="text" name="quantity1" size="6">
Flip Quantity<input type="text" name="flipqty1" size="6">
<br />

<input type="submit" name="value" value="submit" />
</form>
```

my php:

```
<?php


// Include the main TCPDF library 
//(search for installation path).

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');


// create new PDF document

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);


// set document information

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

$pdf->SetTitle('proto_addendum');

$pdf->SetSubject('jobnum');


// set default header data

$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 01', PDF_HEADER_STRING);


// set header and footer fonts

$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));

$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));


// set default monospaced font

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);


// set margins

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);


// set auto page breaks

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);


// set image scale factor

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


// ---------------------------------------------------------


// IMPORTANT: disable font subsetting to allow users editing the document

$pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);


// set font

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10, '', false);


// add a page

$pdf->AddPage();


//data
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Job Number ". $_POST["jobnum"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,5, "Program ". $_POST["program"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,10, "Ship Date ". $_POST["shipdate"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,15, "Description ". $_POST["description"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,20, "Proto Verified By ". $_POST["name"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,25, "Additional Notes ". $_POST["notes"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,30, "File Name". $_POST["filename1"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,35, "Doc Siize ". $_POST["Docsize1"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,40, "FC ". $_POST["fc1"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,45, "DC ". $_POST["dc1"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,50, "Flip ". $_POST["flip1"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,55, "Quantity ". $_POST["quantity1"], $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,60, "Flip Quantity ". $_POST["flipqty1"], $border=0, $ln=0,   $fill=false, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);




// Add Javascript code

$pdf->IncludeJS($js);


// ---------------------------------------------------------


//Close and output PDF document

$pdf->Output('job.pdf', 'D');

?>
```

*edit* - 
thanks... This is the warning that I recieve: Warning: require_once(tcpdf_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet2\pdfcreate.php on line 26 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'tcpdf_include.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet2\pdfcreate.php on line 26

*edit2* - moved some stuff around and now this is the error i am receiving: Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet2\pdfcreate.php on line 31

**edit3** can anyone help? im stuck.

*edit4* I might be getting somewhere. changed tcpdf_include.php to just tcpdf.php then:
 Notice: Undefined index: fc1 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet2\pdfcreate.php on line 117 Notice: Undefined index: dc1 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet2\pdfcreate.php on line 119 Notice: Undefined index: flip1 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet2\pdfcreate.php on line 121  TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I believe that my problem is the check boxes. is there a way if they are not set that this will go through?

*edit 5* i fixed the checkbox issue but i am still getting "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file"

Comment: A blank page (or "500 Internal Server Error" status code) means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code properly without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: Please note that you can (and should) *edit* your question when you have further info. Whatever, the error message is quite clear...

Comment: It's not finding this file `require_once('tcpdf_include.php');`

Comment: "No such file or directory" means exactly that: you do not have `tcpdf_include.php` in the same directory that `pdfcreate.php`.

Comment: Then you haven't included the file in which class `TCPDF` is defined before you create it the first time (by `new TCPFD` or similar)

Comment: @h2ooooooo - what exactly do I need to do? I am really confused at this point.

Comment: does anyone know what to do?

Comment: For edit 4/5, the lazy way is to just turn off error display.  The notices being spit out prevent TCPDF from sending a PDF content type header.  Alternatively, use `isset` to check that a `$_POST` key exists before trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

To find errors with require_once try something like:

```
$filename = realpath('tcpdf_include.php');
var_dump($filename);
```

It outputs *bool(false)* when something went wrong.

To check whether it's just a problem with saving the pdf try just to display the file for a try:

```
$pdf->Output($pdfSavePathFilename, 'I');
```

To test whether it's an access-rights related problem try:

```
fopen($pdfSavePathFilename,'w+');
```

To disable php warnings during tests use:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Just realised that this sums up some answers from

Comment: Does a minimalistic example work so far? Only MultiCell and directly outputed instead of saved?