# Internal server error (HTTP Error 500) after installing phpmyadmin on a certain domain

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm getting internal server error (HTTP Error 500) after installing phpmyadmin on a certain domain.

This is what my **config.inc.php** file currently reads.

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';

/* Storage database and tables */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * default = 30
 */
//$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false    allow editing
 *   'blob'   allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'noblob' disallow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'    disallow editing
 * default = blob
 */
//$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = 'false';

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * default display direction (horizontal|vertical|horizontalflipped)
 */
//$cfg['DefaultDisplay'] = 'vertical';


/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
//$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 *
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/**
 * Should error reporting be enabled for JavaScript errors
 *
 * default = 'ask' 
 */
//$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'ask';

/*
 * You can find more configuration options in the documentation
 * in the doc/ folder or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 */
?>
```

What changes do I need to do on this file? I've already followed up various posts but its not helping.
It this the problem with the domain being down?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Server issues should be asked on serverfault.com.

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" status code (or a blank page) means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: Have you installed this on a server you can SSH into? Or do you have a control panel like cPanel or similar? You'll need to check the logs (or modify PHP/the script to output errors like @ÁlvaroG.Vicario mentioned above), to find out what the problem is.

Comment: @aleayr yes installed it on the server where you can SSH into. I don't have cPanel. Just extracted phpmyadmin files in the folder on the server

Comment: Do you have access to check out the logs for your webserver? If you're running Apache for example, you can try a couple of things: [1] your virtual host for the domain will probably be located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/<vhost>, or /etc/httpd/sites-available/<vhost>. Jump into that file and check for an ErrorLog line to see where Apache is logging errors for this domain to. [2] Just try going to /var/log/apache2/error.log (or /var/log/httpd/error.log) and see if you can see the error. Post it back here, and we may be able to help interpret any errors you find in the logs.

Comment: I've not given the rights to access these files. Thank you anyways for the help

Comment: I'm actually seeing in the logs `libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php on line 1544" while reading response header from upstream` after upgrading to 4.8.  Double checked permissions but I don't know whats causing it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you are using apache2.4 and PHP 7, run

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
```

then restart your server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you.

Comment: This fixed it for me. It's odd that these packages don't come prebundled with Ubuntu's "LAMP" package ( `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` ) and do not appear to be mentioned in the phpMyAdmin documentation.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 php 7 is default and this is the solution to fix 500 error.

Answer (score 7):

I know it has been a couple of years, and I noticed by your comments that still no luck. Here I run into the same 500 error after installing through apt.
I look for my Apache error log file (/var/log/apache2/error.log), and there was the following entry:

```
[Thu Aug 11 22:38:25.930453 2016] [:error] [pid 18138] [client ::1:35026] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 477
```

It shows that the library gettext was not found, so I intalled it:

```
sudo apt-get install  php-gettext
```

And restarted Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That worked for me. Hope it helps.
PS: If still not working you may try to sym link the folder just in case:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, if you have already installed packages **php-mbstring** and **php-gettext** and it still doesn't work, first take a look to Apache logs:

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

If you find something like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected "apply" tag 
>   (expecting closing tag for the "if" tag defined near line 17). in 
>   /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates/columns_definitions/column_virtuality.twig 
>   on line 17

[This is a known bug in phpmyadmin 4.9.4](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=954766)

The bug has been fixed in phpmyadmin 4.9.5 but please note that if you are under Debian 10 Buster you will need to upgrade the package **php-twig** to an higher version rather than the one included with Buster, or package phpmyadmin
will be kept back to 4.9.4 during system upgrades.

You can simply upgrade php-twig from next Debian version (11, Bullseye)

```
apt-get install php-twig/bullseye
```

This worked for me.
Hope this doesn't broke something else in Deb 10 LAMP setup.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your PHP version matches the used PHP module in Apache2:

```
php -v  //PHP 7.4.4 
ls -d /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*.conf // php7.3.conf

sudo a2dismod php7.3  // disable 7.3
sudo a2enmod php7.4   // enable 7.4
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

*I installed the `php-mbstring` `php-gettext` (also excplicitly for latest PHP version), but it still wasn't working. At least it took me hours until I noticed apache decides itself what PHP version is used.*

Answer (score 2):

After applying all the above mentioned solution, none worked for me.

This worked for me:

I thing this error comes from a phpmyadmin library

So, we need to modify following File

File Location : /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php

Line No : 614

run following command in ubuntu terminal

sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
Replace two codes :

Replace : (count($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’] == 1)

With : (count($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’]) == 1)

Replace : && ($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’][0] == ‘*’)))

With : && ($analyzed_sql_results[‘select_expr’][0] == ‘*’))

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the mysql data from your server to your computer

you need to change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to you server ip address.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'your.server.ip.add.here';
```

---

update

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'your.server.ip.add.here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'db name here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'db password';
```

make sure that those fields are properly set up..

Comment: Even that didn't help

Comment: it would help if you could post any error so we can check what really is happening..