# PHPMyadmin HTTP 500 after PHP 5.6 upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, virtualhost

I am in need of assistance. I am unable to access phpMyAdmin on my DO VPS after just recently upgrading the system to PHP5.6. I have done a lot of research over the past few day but to no avail. I want to list out everything that I have to do to see if anybody has any words of wisdom. The most recent this I attempted I found in this SO Answer

[Internal server error (HTTP Error 500) after installing phpmyadmin on a certain domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699774/internal-server-error-http-error-500-after-installing-phpmyadmin-on-a-certain)

I checked my Apache Logs and this line stood out

```
[Tue Nov 29 02:42:20.684526 2016] [:error] [pid 12443] [client 66.169.11.19:56234] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 395
```

So I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gettext
```

And received the following response

```
Note, selecting 'php5.6-common' instead of 'php5.6-gettext'
php5.6-common is already the newest version.
php5.6-common set to manually installed.
```

I would like to point out an oddity that may assist.

Everytime I restart Apache I get this Warning:

```
[Tue Nov 29 02:42:11.553293 2016] [so:warn] [pid 12438] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
```

Can anybody assist me with this?

Here is my Vhost for phpMyAdmin

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@localhost
        DocumentRoot "/usr/share/phpmyadmin"
        ServerName pma.example.net

        ErrorLog "/var/log/pma-error.log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/pma-access.log" combined

        <Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Not only am I unable to access at the sub domain that I have set up I am also unable to access it from [Server IP Address]/phpmyadmin

I receive an HTTP 500.

Thank you.

Comment: Why `php5.6-gettext`? Have you searched what `gettext` packages are available for your distribution?

Comment: im lazy so i would just revert to previous php version :D

Comment: Need PHP5.6 for Laravel 5.3 or I would have

Comment: @jeroen Shamefully no. I noticed in another forum similar to the error that somebody said running PHP5.6-get text fixed their problem after see the Log line that I included. Thought I would give it a try

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may solve the problem is to remove PHPMyAdmin, and reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin

sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

By doing this, you'll give Ubuntu a chance to install the appropriate dependencies for phpmyadmin. Chances are, this will configure your packages in further ways that just installing a newer PHP version doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should run http://pma.example.net

And restarted Apache:

sudo service apache2 restart