# Error 500 : Internal Server Error when open phpPgAdmin PostgreSQL in CPanel

Tags: postgresql, cpanel, phppgadmin

I'm using **PostgreSQL in CPanel**

and I was able access the phpPgAdmin normally and dealing with the databases through it,

But now when I try to reach phpPgAdmin as normal it takes a long time and then a problem appears says:

"Internal Server Error
500
Error ID a465ccfde05b"

I did not find any solutions to the problem on the Internet, and I don't know how to solve it

I'm trying to access phpPgAdmin in CPanel

Comment: I suggest you check the web server (Apache?) error logs. If you're running on a hosted server, you may need to contact tech support to access those logs.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
Actually I'm running on hosted server but now I can't contact support so I can't reach the logs.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Here is a [similar question for phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699774/internal-server-error-http-error-500-after-installing-phpmyadmin-on-a-certain) that might help you.

Comment: phpMyAdmin works good, the problem with phpPgAdmin for PostgreSQL not phpMyAdmin