# fopen clears file instead writing

Tags: php, apache, fopen

I'm trying to write into a text file via PHP. My problem is that PHP always just clears the file instead of writing in it.

```
$fp = fopen('status.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, "test");
fclose($fp);
```

I guess this depends on some permission issues. But I can't figure out what to change. At the moment the  permission of the PHP file is:

```
-rwxrwx---  1 www-data www-data  1980 Feb 18 11:25 test8.php
```

the permission of textfile is:

```
-rwxrwx---  1 www-data www-data     0 Feb 18 11:25 status.txt
```

I'm using apache2 on my Raspberry Pi. The PHP script and the text file are stored in Apache main directory `/var/www/`

Comment: I don't think that PHP has permissions to empty a file but not to add bytes. Have you configured PHP to display error messages? What do `fopen()` and `fwrite()` return?

Comment: fopen returns "Resource id#3" and fwrite just returns 0

Comment: Have you understood my question about configuring PHP to display error messages? Do you need help on that?

Comment: yes what do you mean exactly?

Comment: PHP often generates an error message with a text that explains what's wrong and gives a clue on how to fix it. You can configure PHP to display it or omit it. What is your case?

Comment: Please note that you can (and should) edit the original question when you need to provide further details; code in comments is unreadable. Whatever, I'll take that as a *no* — please have a look at [turn on errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).