# How do I enable error reporting in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, xampp, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I'm trying to import an excel sheet which contains more than 18000 records. the error below appeared.
The localhost page isn’t working

> ```
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500
> ```

I tried to change php.ini `max_execution_time` from 30 seconds to 300 seconds but nothing has been changed

**EDIT**

the apache error log file says: [:error] [pid 3680:tid 1724] [client ::1:54491] PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in E:\..............

Comment: What's the error log show?

Comment: Check laravel logs if not then check apache logs....

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" (or a blank page) means your script is throwing an error but PHP is configured to hide it from you. You need to fix it ASAP because coding without the aid of error messages is hard. As quick start, you can set the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` directives in your computer's system-wide `php.ini` file ([details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508)). However, Laravel should have its own error reporting features—make sure you check them out in their documentation.

Comment: the appache error log file says: [:error] [pid 3680:tid 1724] [client ::1:54491] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in E:\\..............

Comment: you may need to increase your memory limit .

Comment: how can I increase it please?

Comment: i've updated my answer with how to increase it .

Comment: thanks all for your support

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Through your `config/app.php`, set `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),` to `true`.

Or in a better way, check out your `.env` file and make sure to set the debug element to true.

**EDIT**

According to the error in your apache2 log:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
> to allocate 24 bytes)

You need to increase your memory limit:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', XXX);
```

Comment: where I can find ini_set please?

Comment: inside your method , be careful and change `XXX` to a valid value , check out more details about this in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits)

Comment: changing in .env helped a lot especially if it is under gitignore, you wouldn't have worries of accidentally committing  it to the repo.

Answer (score 2):

in **.env** file change APP_DEBUG to true

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

set this at the start of your script, this will run your script forever and check your ipv4 address.

Comment: at the beginning of your script

Comment: did you set your "debug" = true?