# PHP header('location: mypage.php') vs header('location : mypage.php')

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have some basic knowledge of PHP . Once I got an 500 internal error in my Localhost (XAMPP) and it was showing that the server is overloaded. After doing some R&D I got the solution.

I used

`header('location : mypage.php') // Giving me 500 internal error`

The solution was

`header('location: mypage.php') // just removing the space between 'location' and ':'`

So my Question is why it happened ? 
**what is the difference between 'location : mypage.php' and 'location: mypage.php' ?**

Comment: One's the correct [HTTP header syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) and the other isn't?

Comment: One is valid, the other isn't. See [RFC7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#page-22). PHP itself does some parsing for the `Location:` header and ignores invalid ones.

Comment: According to [RFC7230 section-3.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2) Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and optional trailing whitespace.

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" (or a blank page) means your script is throwing an error but PHP is configured to hide it from you. I recommend you fix it in your development box because coding without the aid of error messages is hard. As quick start, you can set the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` directives in your computer's system-wide `php.ini` file ([details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508)). Errors thumb rule: show in development, log in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, you have the wrong syntax when a space is included. It is part of the specifications, which you can read on the W3C site.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30