# PHP PDO statement - working as pdo->query, not working as pdo->prepare

Tags: php, pdo

I have PHP PDO prepared statement:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='DELETE') {
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $action = $request->action;
    if ($action == "delete_todo") {
        $id=$request->id;
        $sql="DELETE from tblTodo where id=?";      
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$id]);
   }
}
```

I am using Boomerang to test API and every time this script return me "500 internal server error". If I change the code to:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='DELETE') {
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $action = $request->action;
    if ($action == "delete_todo") {
        $id=$request->id;
        $sql="DELETE from tblTodo where id=".$id;     
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
   }
}
```

evrything work as it should. What am I doing wrong in PDO prepared statement?

Comment: Check your logs and use proper error handling.

Comment: `$stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $stmt->execute();` that makes your query execute twice, btw.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't check that when I rewrote it to unprepared statement. It is working anyway because of query :)

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" (or a blank page) means your script is throwing an error but PHP is configured to hide it from you. As quick start, you can set the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` directives in your computer's system-wide `php.ini` file ([details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508)).

Comment: what is the version of PHP? and consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't have access to php.ini or server logs. I only have ftp access to one directory.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner PHP version is 5.3.7

Comment: Ok I logged and echoed $id (commented PDO part completely) and it returns me correct id

Comment: your version of php does not support `[]`.

Comment: Thank you, I will contact server Admin to check logs. But I did everything as described in PDO manual and banged my head to wall :)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner you mean that  $stmt->execute([$id]) is not supported by this version of PHP?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner you are life saver! I rewrote to:  $sql="DELETE from tblTodo where id=:id";    $stmt -> execute (array('id' => $id));    and everything is working now. Please add your comment as answer so I can accept it

Comment: @Tomislav Glad I was of help, it has been done. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested.

Your version of PHP (5.3.7) does not support the `[]` array syntax for `$stmt->execute([$id]);`.

Therefore you need to change it to `(array('id' => $id)).`

The manual on arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php states:

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].