# Filtering XML data (Removing Duplicate Values)

Tags: php, xml

Learning how to use PHP playing around with a test store generating a grid of products from XML data.

**Question:**
I want to make a filter and i'm struggling with taking the data from the XML and removing duplicate category values.

[image: Dropdown box]

Below is a template of the XML:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>0</id>
        <url>product-image.jpg</url>
        <category>Ferraro</category>
        <price>$10.00</price>
        <rating>0</rating>
        <comment>NA</comment>
    </product>
```

My attempt of working on the php

```
function removeDup()
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $seen = array();
    $productCount = $xml->product->count();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $productCount; $i++) {
        $seen[] = $xml->product[$i]->category;
        // $seen[$i];
    }
    echo array_unique($seen);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some remarks in no particular order:

- You're looping elements in a pretty convoluted way. SimpleXML objects are iterable when applies, so you can use a simple [`foreach` construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).
- [array_unique()](https://php.net/array_unique) returns an array and you cannot `echo` arrays. If, as it seems, you aren't getting *PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion* from PHP that means that you haven't configured your PHP environment to report errors. As quick start, you can set the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` directives in your computer's system-wide `php.ini` file ([details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508)).
- SimpleXML methods typically returns objects (instances of the `SimpleXMLElement` class). You often want to force a cast to string, or whatever other type you need, when it doesn't happen automatically.

Said that, **your code works fine** as far as I can tell. Both your XML and PHP samples are incomplete so it's possible that the error is somewhere else.

In any case, another possible approach would be to generate a key for the array using the unique field (or fields). That way, each new duplicate element automatically overwrites the previous one. This has the added benefit of being able to retrieve additional fields which may not be identical:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>0</id>
        <url>product-image.jpg</url>
        <category>Ferraro</category>
        <price>$10.00</price>
        <rating>0</rating>
        <comment>NA</comment>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <url>product-image.jpg</url>
        <category>Ferraro</category>
        <price>$10.00</price>
        <rating>0</rating>
        <comment>NA</comment>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <url>product-image.jpg</url>
        <category>Another one</category>
        <price>$10.00</price>
        <rating>0</rating>
        <comment>NA</comment>
    </product>
</products>
```

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: could not load data");
$seen = [];
foreach ($xml->product as $product) {
    // Just an example to ilustrate the posibilites
    $category = (string)$product->category;
    $product_count = $seen[$category]['product_count'] ?? 0;
    $seen[$category] = [
        'category_name' => $category,
        'product_count' => $product_count + 1,
    ];
}
var_dump($seen);
```

```
array(2) {
  ["Ferraro"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["category_name"]=>
    string(7) "Ferraro"
    ["product_count"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["Another one"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["category_name"]=>
    string(11) "Another one"
    ["product_count"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. How can I then use those values when generation my option values for my dropdown?

Comment: My code is just a more elaborate example to show how to do more complex stuff. You don't need it—yours works fine. Whatever your problem is (in fact, you don't really say) it must be somewhere else. If you actually mean that you want to consider "Ferraro" and "Ferraro kitchen" as the same thing, well, that's a completely different problem. What would be the ruleset to decide that, even for a human being?

Comment: I see, I have worked on it and the problem i'm getting is once the array has removed the duplicate values the values still have the same id so when I try to echo them out the first id is 0 but the next unique value has an id of 152.

Should I be resorting them or what is the most efficient way? I also found using the array_unique quite slow loading the data that way.

Comment: There are duplicate values of "Ferraro" up to 151 and then 152 is "Mestre" when calling the items once the duplicates are removed are still $seen[0] and $seen[152] to access those values