# Create a thumbnail from a pdf

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I have to create a thumbnail (in png or jpg) from a pdf. I found the library Imagik and it need GhostScript. Both are intalled on the host but the code doesn't work. I found there in the official docs. I tested in an other php file with an image header but unsuccessfully. Does I have to create an other php file with an image header and test if the file already exist ?

```php
<?php
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=*db url*;dbname=teg;charset=utf8', *user*, *password*);
}
catch (Exception $e){
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM kiosque ORDER BY date_publication DESC');

while ($kiosque = $reponse->fetch())
{
    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->setResolution(400, 565);
    $im->readImage('/resources/kiosque/'. $kiosque['edition'] . '.pdf[0]');
    $im->writeImages('/resources/kiosque/' . $kiosque['edition'] . '.png', false);
?>

<div class="edition">
    <img src="/resources/kiosque/<?php echo $kiosque['edition'];?>.png"></img>
    <h2>Edition #<?php echo $kiosque['numero']; ?></h2>
    <h3 class="date"><?php echo $kiosque['date_publication'];?></h3> 
    <p><?php echo $kiosque['description'];?></p>
    <a class="button" href="lire.php?numero=<?php echo $kiosque['numero'];?>&amp;date=<?php echo $kiosque['date_publication'];?>&amp;edition=<?php echo $kiosque['edition'];?>">Lire cette édition</a>
</div>

<?php
}

$reponse->closeCursor();
?>
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: The page does't load, or not the parent contener

Comment: Are you sure your file paths for reading the PDF and writing the image are correct? They look like they are relative to the wed server's document root, not the root of the filesystem.

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" (or a blank page) means your script is throwing an error but PHP is configured to hide it from you. You need to fix it ASAP because coding without the aid of error messages is hard. As quick start, you can set the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` directives in your computer's system-wide `php.ini` file ([details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508)). Errors thumb rule: show in development, log in production.

Comment: `PHP message: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$im' on line 37`

Comment: and rob, I have to give a relative file paths to the filesystem ?

Comment: You're getting an error in line #37 of a 31-line file...

Comment: oh it's because this code is a part of the file, but the #37 line is `$im = new Imagick();`

Comment: it's a part in an html page

Comment: But it's a syntax error anyway. Your code is not even running!

Comment: but why `$im` is unexpected ? I have to declare this ?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself correctly. You say you're having problems with certain library, but the story told by the error message is that you aren't even using the library since your PHP code has a syntax error and cannot run (it isn't possible to run PHP code that's invalid PHP code). However [there aren't syntax errors in the code you've shared](https://3v4l.org/TFsQb) unless you're running PHP/4 (an obsolete version from 16 years ago nobody's using any more). Unfortunately the question you ask is unrelated to the problem you have.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm french, but I don't have, I think, problems with the libraries because both are installed on the host, but I don't know why I have an error, the syntax is correct. Have you any solution ?