# Is there a way to use Chrome's “inspect element” to locate the HTML file that is in view?

Tags: php, html, browser, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I have seen other questions that are similar but the answers are not suitable. Inspect Element allows you to inspect an element and then change the element, whether it be text or anything else.

It seems intuitive that a developer should also be able to locate the file name from inspect element, e.g. to find out where a particular element is located.

Currently, I have a link that goes to a blank page. I cannot find the associated pages (that are responsible for loading this page in its entirety) in my public_html.

if not, using inspect_element, can anyone suggest a way to use the browser to somehow find out what file is being loaded - e.g. which HTML page/pages.

For the specific example, I am referring to this (the below URL loads a blank page). I can find topic.php but there is something else going on - perhaps header files or footer, that is causing the page not to load, and I cannot locate these files.

http://teachingcomputing.com/topic.php

Any thoughts or developer tips appreciated.

Comment: The only things I have in my mind is the CSS and JavaScript ones if they are separate files.

Comment: While possible (and we cannot forget static site generators), it's extremely rare nowadays to find a complex site built entirely of static HTML files. And if it's even the case, the browser has no way to know. Furthermore, if your URL ends in `.php` we can be pretty sure that [you don't have a static site at all](https://php.net/).

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" (or a blank page) means your script is throwing an error but PHP is configured to hide it from you. You need to address that first because coding without the aid of error messages is hard. As quick start, you can set the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` directives in your computer's system-wide `php.ini` file ([details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508)). Errors thumb rule: show in development, log in production.